# AWK - replacement of the two commands 'printf, print' single command 'printf'?

Tags: awk, printf, getline

Please help this problem.

I have this command:

```
awk 'BEGIN {printf "%-15s", "Date of birth:" > "/dev/stderr"; getline var; print "Today finished:", var ,"days"}'
```

How do I print 'var' with only the first command 'printf'? Can I remove the second command 'print'?

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT-1:**

> answer for **Mat**

The first example is good, but prints 'var' in the next line. Is it possible to print the 'var' in the same line?

**EDIT-2:**

> answer for **Peter.O**

Thank you for your help. Exactly the point. Data will be used for further calculations. Result of the calculation will be printed in the same line. Example:

```
awk 'BEGIN {printf "%-15s", "Date of birth:" > "/dev/stderr"; getline var; print "Today finished:", var ,"days"}'`
```

That I want to get the result:

```
Date of birth: 2011-02-23 Today finished: 2011-02-23 days
```

**EDIT-3:**

> answer for **shellter**

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Why? What you have in the first example works, doesn't it?

Comment: The first example is good, but prints 'var' in the next line.
Is it possible to print the 'var' in the same line?

Comment: Do you really want *awk* to print *var* on the same line, when the user has just entered that same value on that same line? ... and why is there so much whitespace after the prompt `Enter the date:             `?  Is that where you want the user to type in the date?  It would help if you **showed** an actual example of how you expect the finished line to look like. because at the moment it is confusing and to me it seems that you want it to look like: `Enter the date:              2012-03-17 2012-03-17` ...

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Exactly the point. Data will be used for further calculations. Result of the calculation will be printed in the same line. Example: `awk 'BEGIN {printf "%-15s", "Date of birth:" > "/dev/stderr"; getline var; print "Today finished:", var ,"days"}'` That I want to get the result: `Date of birth: 2011-02-23  Today finished: 2011-02-23 days`

Comment: It's hard to read stuff in comments, you can edit your original question and use the formatting tools on the top of the text input box to make your question more legible. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example code, you have redirected `printf` to stderr. I assume that is because you don't want `"Enter the date:"`  going to the final output (stdout) which will be further processed ... That works and is a clean way of disposing of that unwanted text.

So if you want your formatted output:
   `Date of birth: 2011-02-23 Today finished: 2011-02-23 days`
to go to standard output (stdout), then the answer to your question is simple: You definitely need to call another instance of `print/printf` which is directed  to standard out.

`print/printf` has no concept of **where** its output is going; it just **prints** ... The redirection operator `>` has no connection whatsoever to the **internal** workings of print(f), so you can't get a single call of print(f) to send some output to `stderr` and the rest to `stdout`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Now you can manage. I have such a question. How do I confirm that I got a good response?

Comment: At the top left of each answer is a number with arrow-heads above and another below it. To mark an answer as good and useful, you click on the upper arrow; this increments the number. To mark the answer as bad, click the lower arrow to decrement the counter. The question asker (you) also has another option, ie. to accept the **best** answer by clicking the big tick below the bottom arrow. This typically means that the questioner can mark one or more answers up/down, and after allowing time for better answers to appear, you mark the **best** answer (via the tick).